How do I format R Plotly axis to show ticks in gigabytes instead of billions?
Edited:
I am working on a bar chart that represents database size at the beginning of each month. Please see the simplification of my code below:
library(plotly)

fig <-
  plot_ly(type = 'bar',
          x = ~c('2024-01-01', '2024-02-01', '2024-03-01', '2024-04-01'),
          y = ~c(462739776472, 464468500807, 464865785285, 464865785290)) %>%
  layout(
    xaxis = list(
      title = 'Date'),
    yaxis = list(
      title = 'DB Size'
    )
  )

fig

I get the following graph:

Now I would like my y axis to show gigabytes instead of billions. I can do it using an "array" tickmode method and manually assigning ticktext and tickvals as shown below:
library(plotly)

fig <-
  plot_ly(type = 'bar',
          x = ~c('2024-01-01', '2024-02-01', '2024-03-01', '2024-04-01'),
          y = ~c(462739776472, 464468500807, 464865785285, 464865785290)) %>%
  layout(
    xaxis = list(
      title = 'Date'),
    yaxis = list(
      title = 'DB Size',
      ticktext = list('100G', '200G', '300G', '400G'),
      tickvals = list(100000000000, 200000000000, 300000000000, 400000000000),
      tickmode = 'array'
    )
  )

fig

I am getting what I want:

However, database size could drastically change. Therefore I do not want to hardcode my tick values and labels. Is there a method to programmatically change tick formats such as tickformat? If so, what is the tickformat code for bytes, gigabytes, terabytes notation? Where can I find a list of common tickformat codes? If tickformat is not the way to go, which other methods can I use to achieve the graphic above without manually assigning tick labels? Thank you.

@Dubukay, I have updated my question with new values.

I couldn't tell what the order of your comments and edits were - are you still having trouble with this? The convention for a barplot is to draw the rectangles all the way down to zero and that's pretty well hard-coded into the plotly library. A couple options - one, switching from bars to points is super easy ("scatter" instead of "bar"), or two, telling plotly exactly what kind of y-range it should have instead (maybe yrange <- as.list(range(yvals)+c(-1, 1)*sd(yvals)) and yaxis = list(range=yrange) instead?

Here's one option, using base R's pretty to create breaks and the scales package for the label_bytes function:
yvals <- c(50000000000, 150000000000, 250000000000, 450000000000)
tv <- pretty(yvals)
tx <- scales::label_bytes()(tv)

fig <-
  plot_ly(type = 'bar',
          x = ~c('2024-01-01', '2024-02-01', '2024-03-01', '2024-04-01'),
          y = ~yvals) %>%
  layout(
    xaxis = list(
      title = 'Date'),
    yaxis = list(
      title = 'DB Size',
      ticktext = tx,
      tickvals = tv,
      tickmode = 'array'
    )
  )


This works with all kinds of sizes:
yvals <- c(10000000, 15000000, 25000000, 45000000)



Note: if you always want to label down to the 0 on the y-axis, you can paste on a zero to the front end: pretty(c(0, yvals))

Thank you for providing a solution. It works perfectly with the mockup numbers I provided. In reality, the numbers are a lot closer in value. How do I force the evenly spaced labels, say every 100 GB, to be displayed on the axis? For example plot your solution with yvals <- c(462739776472, 464468500807, 464865785285, 464865785290).

Apologies, I forgot to add 0 to the front of tickvals. Thank you!
